# UnicodeEncodeError in Mako Template

Tags: python, mako

I have the following files

**dummy.py**

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe -u

from mako import exceptions
from mako.template import Template

print "Content-type: text/html"
print

#VARIABLE = "WE" 
VARIABLE = "我们"
template = Template(filename='../template/dummy.html', output_encoding='utf8')
try:
    print template.render(VARIABLE=VARIABLE)
except:
    print exceptions.html_error_template().render()
```

---

**dummy.html** (Saved in UTF-8 format)

```
hello world
哈罗世界
${VARIABLE}
```

I had refereed to the instruction from http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/unicode.html

However, I still get error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec
>   can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 0:
>   ordinal not in range(128)

Anything I had missed out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template = Template(filename='../template/dummy.html', default_filters=['decode.utf8'], input_encoding='utf-8', output_encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because you are trying to render it to ASCII, which doesn't work. You need to say what output_encoding to use:

```
Template(filename='../template/dummy.html', output_encoding='utf8')
```

And please don't have bare excepts. Add what exceptions you expect to catch.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't make my problem statement accurate. I re-phrase it, the problem is lying in parsing the variable.

Comment: @Yan Check CHEOK: That's because you aren't using Unicode for your variables. Change `"我们"` to `u"我们"` and you are in business.